# Is there a way to determine if an event is initiated by a user action?

Tags: cytoscape.js

```
const cyEvents = 'move select drag unselect viewport';

cy.on(cyEvents, (e) => {
  // e.type is 'viewport' on graph render
});
```

With the above code, the inner event handler fires right away when the graph renders, even though the user hasn't interacted with the graph at all.

Is there a way to either stop this event from firing, or preferably is there a means to tell the source of the event, e.g. did Cytoscape cause the event to fire programmatically, or was it caused by a user interacting with the graph (mouse event, etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

You can put a listener for each type of event if that's work for you.

```
cy.on('tap', 'node', function(evt){
  let node = evt.target;
  console.log( 'tapped ' + node.id() );
});
```

This already mentioned [in the documentation](https://js.cytoscape.org/#core/events). Also, don't forget to remove your listeners with `cy.off(`. If you add a listener multiple times, they will be called multiple times.

--- edit 1 ---
Again in the documentation, it says

[image: https://js.cytoscape.org/#events]

So in the event handler function, you can check if any of these arguments exist. Also, I think your problem is not clear. maybe you can prepare a minimal reproducible sample.

Also, if you want to mark the graph as dirty, you can simply listen to the events that are only fired by direct user interaction. When does are fired you can set your mark.

Comment: That's not quite what I'm looking for. My issue is that when the graph initially displays, it's firing events such as "viewport". I want to watch for user interaction and mark the graph as dirty when the user pans the graph, etc., and since Cytoscape is firing those events without user interaction, it's making it hard to accomplish.

Comment: You can use cy.ready to bind the events after cytoscape has rendered?